# Has "Extraordinary" Ever Been Spelled with an A-O Ligature?

Tags: etymology, orthography, history, typography, ligature

For example, instead of spelling it as `extraordinary`, you would write it as `extrꜵrdinary`.

This also applies to its derivations, such as instead of `extraordinaire`, you would write `extrꜵrdinaire`.

I'm aware that in the early days of European metallic typesetting, [ligatures were often used as an effort-saving method](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2009-m10/0071.html) (less matrices would need to be made). Gutenberg started using his printing press commercially around 1450 CE, and the earliest known usage of the word *extraordinary* according to the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67124?redirectedFrom=extraordinary#eid) was in 1460 CE (see below). So it may have been a plausible option for them to have done this for the same reason.

---

**Note**: The OED entry requires a subscription, so I included the quote it references here:

> c1460 J. Fortescue *Governance of Eng.* (1714) 39 "The Kyngs yerly expencs stondyn in chargs Ordynarye, and in chargs Extraordynary."

Comment: I am not sure your question is about the English language usage:    ***extraordinary (adj.)*** 
early 15c., from Latin extraordinarius "out of the common order," from extra ordinem "out of order," especially the usual order, from extra "out" (see extra-) + ordinem, accusative of ordo "order" (see order (n.)). Related: Extraordinarily; extraordinariness.
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Extraordinary&searchmode=none

Comment: I have no fonts on my PC here which cope with that Unicode character :-(

Comment: In certain older texts (typically British), ***the use of the ligatures æ and œ is common in words such as archæology, diarrhœa, and encyclopædia.*** Such words have Latin or Greek origin. Nowadays, the ligatures have been generally replaced in British English by the separated digraph ae and oe (encyclopaedia, diarrhoea); but usually economy, ecology, and in American English by e (encyclopedia, diarrhea; but usually paean, amoeba, oedipal, Caesar). In some cases, usage may vary; for instance, both encyclopedia and encyclopaedia are current in the UK.

Comment: @Josh61: the question is about "a - o ligature", not about ae or oe.

Comment: Letters and diacritics originating as ligatures : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Letters_and_diacritics_originating_as_ligatures

Comment: There being so few words with *ao* in English, and there being no linguistic reason to join these letters in *extraordinary*, do you have any reason to believe these two letters would have been chosen for a ligature other than the current pronunciation of the word (which was probably not the pronunciation in 1600, as if it had been, we would likely be spelling it *extrordinary* today)?

Comment: And judging from Shakespeare, *extraordinary* had six syllables at the end of the 16th century. Otherwise, the following lines containing that word would not have scanned: *These signs have mark'd me extraordinary* and *Afford no extraordinary gaze*.

Comment: @PeterShor I've heard it pronounced with 6 syllables and not just for emphasis. It would come across as both posh and old-fashioned -- a bit 1950s BBC.

Comment: @Josh61: Yes, it was. It may not be about contemporary English language usage, but rather historical usage, but that still qualifies as usage.

Also, I already knew all that about contemporary usage. I was asking purely about historical usage.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, I figured it was unlikely. This was mere speculation, that's all. A curiosity question, merely.

Comment: Also, I would agree with @ChrisH: I often say it myself with 6 syllables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not, at least from Google's perspective. The 
[Google ngram viewer for extrꜵrdinary](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extr%EA%9C%B5rdinary&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1200&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) returns no results from 1500 to 2000.

Comment: Thanks. Quite the awesome answer. I love answers that gives data-backed responses to speculative questions. 

Comment: Yes, sorry. I can't down-vote myself unfortunately. A google ngram search is flawed and probably doesn't really address your question for many reasons, the least of which is that perhaps any ligatures in old scanned text are torn-apart to fit with Unicode character set. And of course, I should have taken into account historic spelling: [link] (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Extraordynary&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextraordynary%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: It's okay. We can only do our best. :)

And I'm sorry; did my comment seem sarcastic? :/ Because I was serious. I like your answer...a lot.

Comment: The ambiguity of asynchronous communication... :) . No problem, in fact it was the praise that made me question whether that was really an awesome answer. I have just checked, though, and 'encyclopædia" does show up in google's ngram interface as far back as 1582, so the absence of extraordinary with a ligature may be meaningful. [link] (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=encyclop%C3%A6dia&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cencyclop%C3%A6dia%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BEncyclop%C3%A6dia%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bencyclop%C3%A6dia%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Lol, I totally understand *that* feeling. And yes I would agree. It would seem that if it were used, we would probably see at least a few etymological "fossils", so-to-speak. The fact that it doesn't show up (and sure, it's only Google, but Google has a **huge** database) I think means something. Either that or most of the only known examples have been eradicated via the Unicode ablation you mentioned, which is I think unlikely to have eliminated all of the remainders.

Comment: Haha, *Unicode ablation*... Now THAT is a term I'm proud of having made up. Better yet:

*"code ablation": n. The gradual elimination of digital units of communication through multiple instances of simplification.*